# Solving $\cos z = i$ for $z$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Solve $\cos z = i$ for $z$.

What I have tried:
$$\cos z = i$$
$$\frac{e^{-zi}+e^{zi}}{2}=i$$
$$e^{-zi}+e^{zi}=2i=2e^{\frac\pi 2 + 2\pi k},\quad k\in \Bbb Z$$

I would take logs, but then I would have two terms in the left log, what now?

---

I have the solution for the problem already (this hasn't helped me since they have shown no work):
$$-i\ln (\sqrt2 +1)+\left(2k+\frac12\right)\pi, \quad -i\ln(\sqrt 2 - 1) +\left(2k-\frac12\right)\pi, \qquad k\in \Bbb Z.$$

Comment: That is the incorrect form for $\cos z$.  It actually is $\cos z = \frac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2}$.

Comment: @Mnifldz Better?

Comment: Hint: let $u=e^{iz}$ and you'll have a quadratic which is easily solvable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align}
& e^{iz} + e^{-iz} = 2i \\
& e^{2iz} + 1 = 2ie^{iz} \qquad \text{(Both sides were multiplied by $e^{iz}$.)} \\
& w^2 + 1 = 2iw \\
& w^2 -2iw = -1 \\
& w^2 - 2iw - 1 = -2 \qquad\text{(completing the square)} \\
& (w- i)^2 = -2 \\
& w-i = \pm i\sqrt 2 \\
& w = i \pm i\sqrt 2 \\
& e^{iz} = i(1\pm\sqrt 2) = e^{i\pi/2} e^{\log(1\pm\sqrt 2)}
\end{align}
etc.
(And notice that $\log(1-\sqrt 2) = -\log(1+\sqrt 2)$.)

Comment: Does $\frac1i = -i$?. Multiply both sides by $i$ and you get $1=1$ so it seems consistent

Comment: @SkiesBurn : Both sides of _what_?  Indeed, $1/i = -i$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3):

You got to $e^{iz}+e^{-iz}=2i$. Let $u=e^{iz}$, this becomes:

$$u+\frac{1}{u}=2i$$
$$u^2+1=2iu$$
$$u^2-2iu+1=0$$
Thus 
$$u=\frac{2i\pm\sqrt{-4-4}}{2}$$

$$ u=\frac{2i\pm i\sqrt{8}}{2}$$
$$ u = i(1\pm\sqrt{2})$$

Then $$e^{iz}=i(1\pm\sqrt{2})$$

Answer (score 3):

It's convenient to use the decomposition of $z$ and $\cos z$ into real and imaginary parts, namely,
$$\cos(x + iy) = \cos x \cosh y - i \sin x \sinh y$$
(for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$).

Using this formula to decompose $\cos z = i$ into real and imaginary parts gives the (equivalent) system
\begin{align}
\cos x \cosh y &= 0 \\
\sin x \sinh y &= 1  .
\end{align}

> Now, $\cosh y > 0$ for all $y$, so the first equation is equivalent to $\cos x = 0$, which has solution $$x = \pi\left(m + \frac{1}{2}\right), \quad m \in \mathbb{Z}.$$ We can now substitute for $x$ in the other equation; in particular, $$\sin \pi\left(m + \frac{1}{2}\right) = (-1)^m,$$ so the second equation becomes $$(-1)^m \sinh y = 1,$$ and solving gives (recall here that $\sinh$ is injective, and so $\text{arsinh}$ is a bona fide inverse) $$y = \text{arsinh} [(-1)^m] = (-1)^m \ln(1 + \sqrt{2}).$$ So, the solutions of $\cos z = i$ are precisely $$z = \pi\left(m + \frac{1}{2}\right) + i (-1)^m \ln(1 + \sqrt{2}), \quad m \in \mathbb{Z}.$$ Specializing to $m = 2k$ and $m = 2k + 1$, together with the fact that $(\sqrt{2} + 1)(\sqrt{2} - 1) = 1$ and an appropriate logarithm identity, yields the given solutions.

Answer (score 1):

When you have $e^{-iz} + e^{iz} = 2i$, multiply through with another factor of $e^{iz}$ to obtain $e^{2iz} -2ie^{iz} + 1 = 0$.  Using the quadratic formula we get

$$
e^{iz} \;\; =\;\; \frac{2i \pm \sqrt{-4 - 4}}{2} \;\; =\;\; i(1 \pm \sqrt{2}).
$$

The rest should be straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Following the hint by @avid19:

Let $u=e^{iz}$

$$e^{-zi}+e^{zi}-2e^{\frac\pi 2 + 2\pi k}=0$$
$$\implies u^{-1}+u-2i=0$$
$$u^2-2iu+1=0$$

$$\text{by quadratic formula: } z = \frac{2i\pm\sqrt{-4-4}}{2}$$
$$u=e^{iz}=i\pm\frac{2\sqrt2 i}{2}=i\pm\sqrt{2}i$$
$$e^{iz}=i\pm \sqrt{2}i$$
$$iz = \ln(i\pm \sqrt{2}i)$$
$$z=\frac{\ln(i\pm \sqrt{2}i)}{i}=-i\ln(i\pm \sqrt{2}i)$$

As desired.