# solve the equation: $\cos (z) = 1 + i$ , $z \in ℂ$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to solve the equation:  $\cos (z) = 1 + i$  , $z \in ℂ$.

I started by saying $\cos (z) = \frac {e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2}$.

I am therefore led to solve:
$$e^{iz} + e^{-iz} = 2 + 2i $$ this implies that $$e^{2iz}+1 =(2 + 2i) e^{iz}$$
By setting $x = e^{iz}$

Consider the equation:
$$x^2-(2 + 2i) x + 1 = 0$$
which is equivalent to solving the equation $$ x^2-2 \sqrt{2} e^{i \frac {\pi}{4}} x + 1 = 0$$
then $$ (x- \sqrt{2} e^{i \frac{\pi}{4} })^2 + 1 + 2i = 0$$

We set $$w = x- \sqrt {2} e^{i \frac{\pi}{4}}$$ so $$w^2 = -1-2i$$ But I can't seem to continue. An idea please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving $\cos z = i$ for $z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242873/solving-cos-z-i-for-z)

Comment: Note that $-1-2i = \sqrt{5} e^{i(-\pi+ \arctan(2))} $, which implies that $ w= \pm  5^{\frac{1}{4}} e^{ \frac{i(-\pi+ \arctan(2))}{2}} $ and you can take it from here.

Comment: Try to use the complex definition of the inverse cosine and its analytic extension to simplify $\cos^{-1}(z)=\frac\pi 2+i \ln\left(iz+\sqrt{1+z}\sqrt{1-z}\right)+2k\pi\Bbb Z$

Comment: Since $x^2-2 \sqrt{2} e^{i \frac {\pi}{4}} x + 1 = 0$ is a quadratic equation, maybe you would be better off using the quadratic formula.  You will still have to do a square-root of a complex number.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the [complex definition](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ArcCos/02/) of the inverse cosine and its [analytic extension](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ArcCos/05/) to simplify:

$$\cos^{-1}(z)=\frac\pi 2+i \ln\left(iz+\sqrt{1+z}\sqrt{1-z}\right)+2k\pi\Bbb Z$$
$$\mathop \implies^\text{z=1+i}\cos^{-1}(1+i)=\frac\pi2+i\ln\left(i(1+i)+\sqrt{1-(1+i)^2}\right)=\frac\pi2+i\ln\left(i-1+\sqrt{1-2i}\right)$$

To take a radical of a complex number, use [De Moivre’s theorem](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Extras/ComplexPrimer/Roots.aspx) and $n\in \Bbb Z$:

$$\sqrt{1-2i}=\sqrt[4]{1^2+(-2)^2}e^{\frac12i\left(\tan^{-1}\left(-\frac21\right)+2\pi n\right)}=\sqrt[4]5\cos\left(\frac12 \tan^{-1}(2)\right) + \sqrt[4]5i\sin\left(\frac12 \tan^{-1}(2)\right)=\pm\sqrt[4]5 \sqrt{\frac12+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{10}}\pm\sqrt[4]5\sqrt{\frac{2}{5+\sqrt5}}i$$

Putting it all together gives the general solution of the following. The signs can be chosen to be +,- or -,+:

$$\cos^{-1}(1+i)=i\ln\left(\pm\sqrt[4]5 \sqrt{\frac12+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{10}}-1\mp\sqrt[4]5\sqrt{\frac{2}{5+\sqrt5}}i+i\right)+ \frac\pi2+ 2\pi k, k\in \Bbb Z.$$

[**Proof of result**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%28pi%2F2+%2Bi*ln%285%5E%281%2F4%29sqrt%281%2F2%2Bsqrt5%2F10%29-1-5%5E%281%2F4%29sqrt%282%2F%285%2Bsqrt5%29%29i%2Bi%29%29) for a case. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Answer (score 0):

At this point

$x^2-(2 + 2i) x + 1 = 0.$

Applying the quadratic formula:

$x = 1+i \pm \sqrt {2i - 1}:$

$(1+i + \sqrt {2i - 1})(1+i - \sqrt {2i- 1}) = 2i - (2i-1) = 1$

This means we can let $e^{iz} = 1+i + \sqrt {2i - 1}$ and $e^{-iz} = 1+i - \sqrt {2i - 1}$

$iz = \ln (1+i + \sqrt {2i - 1})\\
z = -i\ln (1+i + \sqrt {2i - 1})$